# how to add form with AJAX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a new.html.slim page with a form

**_form.html.slim**

```
= form_for  (@text_input), remote: true do |f|   
 .field
  = f.text_field :title
  ...
```

**new.html.slim**

```
h1 new text_input
 == render 'form'
 ...
a.btn type='button' href = '#'
  | add another text input
```

how to add  another form to this page with AJAX after click button?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are sure you need the AJAX? if you want just to add another field, use simple jQuery.

If you need some respond from server-side and you are sure about AJAX, write AJAX request as action for the button. To accomplish it, add id to button

```
btn type='button' id='add_form_button'
```

In javascript file for view add the handler for event with AJAX request

```
$(function(){
   $("#add_form_button").click(function(){
       $.get("ajax/result",function(content){
           #in this function should be placement of new form
           #For example, as that
           $("#place_for_field").append(content);
       }
   }
}
```

You should route "ajax/result" to controller and function. In config/routes.rb

```
 get 'ajax/result', to: "controller_name#function_name"
```

In controller with controller_name in function with function_name write logic and response. Also you will need the view for that function.